# ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class

Tags: android

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class

- This error shown while generating signed apk.

  here is my build.gradle

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.jhaider.livefootballmatchesofworldcup"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 25
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      multiDexEnabled true
  }

  packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.xml'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties'


      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/pom.properties'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
      exclude 'META-INF/gson/FieldAttributes.class'
      exclude '.readme'


  }

  dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }

  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          useProguard false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }

  flavorDimensions "app-type"
  productFlavors {
      live1016 {
          applicationId "com.jhaider.livefootballmatchesofworldcup"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 25
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          dimension "app-type"
      }

      videohighlights {
          applicationId "com.jhaider.livefootballmatchesofworldcup.videohighlights"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 25
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          dimension "app-type"
      }
  }
  ```

  sourceSets {
          live1016 {
              java {
                  srcDir 'src/live1016/java'
              }
              resources {
                  srcDir 'src/live1016/res'
              }
          }

  ```
      videohighlights {
          java {
              srcDir 'src/videohighlights/java'
          }
          resources {
              srcDir 'src/videohighlights/res'
          }
      }

  }
  ```

  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  ```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'   
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'

  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
  ```

  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

  ```
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'){

      force=true
  }
  compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'){

      force=true
  }
  compile project(':StartAppInApp-3.6.7')

  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  ```

  }

  // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved by upgrading all the firebase dependencies on `build.gradle` from `15.0.0` to `15.0.2` where available.

Go to https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup for latest versions available and note that latest version for `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads` is `15.0.0` and latest version for `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` is `15.0.2`

Comment: you saved me, you deserve a bells!

Comment: Thanks Buddy You saved my time!

Comment: I tried the same but now I am getting this error

:   `Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.0.`

Answer (score 0):

Delete assets folder entry in the android studio (not from actual folder location). Then do a clean build.

Comment: `Delete assets folder entry in the android studio` Sorry sir, Kindly read error `ZipException: duplicate entry`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downgrade or upgrade library, it would better to exclude one or more of the same class from different versions. For example, if you know from which module the class is from, you can use:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'module.of.dependecy,withconfllict'
}
```